# Angular2 router

Tags: angular, firebase, angular2-routing, angularfire2

I have been creating a web application with Angular2 and Firebase,
first I check if the user is authenticated or not, if user is authenticated, he will be redirect to a page that contains the list of groups otherwise he will be redirect to a login page.
The problem is that the menu and the  header are always visible.
I want the menu and the header of the application  will not be displayed when user redirect to login page.
how I can do this.

app.component.ts

```
  constructor(public af: AngularFire,private  router:Router){
      this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
     if(auth) {
       this.userconnected = auth;
     }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-appheader *ngIf="userconnected"  [userconnected]="userconnected"></app-appheader>
<app-appmenu *ngIf="userconnected" [userconnected]="userconnected" data-spy="affix"></app-appmenu>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<app-appfooter></app-appfooter>
```

app.routes.ts

```
  { path: 'groups', component: ListgroupsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },   
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'groups', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

groups.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit list surveu");
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      if(auth) {
        this.name = auth;
        this.ifInfoUser(this.name.auth.uid)
      }
    });
}


  ifInfoUser(idUser):boolean{
    console.log('BeginifInfoUser');
    const user = this.af.database.object('/users/'+idUser);
    user.subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data");
      if(data.uid!=null){
        this.existUser=true;
        this.router.navigate(['/groups']);
      }else{
        this.existUser=false;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    });

return this.existUser;
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to use a [guard](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html) that will check if the user is authenticated, and then decide what to do based on the information received.

Comment: I have already checked if user is connected or not "*ngIf="userconnected""

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What about your current approach is not working for you? Is the menu always visible? If so you likely have a logic error.

Comment: yes, the problem is that the menu is always visible, even if the user redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong. You are using **router-outlet** in your **app.component.html** with menu and header code that's why the menu and the header of the app will always be displayed when user redirects to login page. The problem is in your rendering because your login page is rendered inside your header and menu div code.

There could be many ways but according to me, your app should firstly show login page If the login is successful then It should redirect to some main page in which you will have header and menu as in your app.component.html.

Comment: If this answer is correct. You can accept it so that it will be helpful for the further users.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to change your `this.userconnected`state on logout.

`app.component.ts` will check and set that value only inside of the `constructor`.

Try to subscribe to `onAuthStateChanged` and set there your `this.userconnected` state.